# sliding glass door not closing flush

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I closed my sliding glass door and noticed that at the bottom of the door where it meets the frame when closed I can see light coming through.

It's only at the bottom of the door so I imagine that the top of the door is meeting the frame earlier than the base of the door.

This [*Adjusting Sliding Glass Doors*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfXdVQjVIak&ab_channel=HomeAdditionPlus) by HomeAdditionPlus seems to present a solid fix by adjusting how the door sits in the track, but I wanted to see if there were other things I should check for? Maybe if the door frame is square?

Comment: From the video simply turn the adjustment screw below the handle 1/4 turn CW. You may have to make it a CW 1/2 turn or so. If the frame is out of alignment you would probably have to remove it, reset it and refinish the surround area. If the door is on a slight angle it will not be noticed. I expect the frame is ok and the door needs adjustment.

Comment: Seeing you do not mention any other problems, like the door is hard to close or open, it is probably just adjustment needed.

Answer (score 0):

The door should be sitting in below the frame rim, so no light comes through.

Use the adjustment screws to do so. (lower it)

Check if the door is parallel to the side frame and adjust the wheel heights accordingly.

That leveling is also used to compensate for small frame not being square.